# Dialogflow v2 client library not working | Error: Could not load the default credentials

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es, google-oauth

here is their sample code:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const uuid = require('uuid');

/**
 * Send a query to the dialogflow agent, and return the query result.
 * @param {string} projectId The project to be used
 */
async function runSample(projectId = 'your-project-id') {
  // A unique identifier for the given session
  const sessionId = uuid.v4();

  // Create a new session
  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

  // The text query request.
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
        text: 'hello',
        // The language used by the client (en-US)
        languageCode: 'en-US',
      },
    },
  };

  // Send request and log result
  const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
  console.log('Detected intent');
  const result = responses[0].queryResult;
  console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
  console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
  if (result.intent) {
    console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
  }
}
```

and this code is not working at all, giving **Error: Could not load the default credentials** :

```
2019-03-21T16:59:40.099101+00:00 app[web.1]: Message: hi Bilal
2019-03-21T16:59:40.102561+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
2019-03-21T16:59:40.102565+00:00 app[web.1]:     at GoogleAuth.<anonymous> (/app/web/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:168:23)
2019-03-21T16:59:40.102568+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
2019-03-21T16:59:40.102570+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fulfilled (/app/web/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:19:58)
2019-03-21T16:59:40.102572+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
2019-03-21T16:59:40.102691+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
2019-03-21T16:59:40.102784+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2019-03-21T16:59:55.986568+00:00 app[web.1]: Message: hi Bilal
2019-03-21T16:59:55.986595+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
2019-03-21T16:59:55.986598+00:00 app[web.1]:     at GoogleAuth.<anonymous> (/app/web/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:168:23)
2019-03-21T16:59:55.986600+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
2019-03-21T16:59:55.986602+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fulfilled (/app/web/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:19:58)
2019-03-21T16:59:55.986605+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
2019-03-21T16:59:55.986647+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

they have instructions how to use this library in the repo but it doesnt makes sense https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow

they have not described anywhere how to put credentials  while calling detect intent, not eve in the example code here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/detect.js

I have never seen such irresponsible team like dialogflow team in my life

## Update:

exporting env variable solved my problem and now I am getting something back from dialogflow but not as expected, may be they have incorrect code in their repository sample code

this is the code they do have as [try an example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow#using-the-client-library):

```
  ...
   
  // Send request and log result
  const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
  console.log('Detected intent');
  const result = responses[0].queryResult;
  console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
  console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
  if (result.intent) {
    console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
  }
  
  ...
```

and in fact `result.fulfillmentText` does not exist, it is giving me undefined

## Update 2

that much effort I have done(see console.logs below) just to understand that instead of `responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentText` now they return `responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages` and it is not a text string but it is an object which have further values in it that you can see in console.logs below:

```
...
 
// Send request and log result
const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
console.log('Detected intent');

console.log("responses: ", responses)
console.log("responses[0]: ", responses[0])
console.log("responses[0].queryResult: ", responses[0].queryResult)
console.log("responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages: ", responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages)
// console.log("responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[1]: ", responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[1])
console.log("responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0]: ", responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0])
console.log("responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text: ", responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text)
console.log("responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text: ", responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text)
console.log("responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0]: ", responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0])

var fulfilmentText = responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0]

 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google auth library is looking for an environment variable called
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS that points to a JSON credentials file.

You can download that file by following instructions as described in https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup.

The link after the error message has examples of how to set that environment variable:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried taking a look at this? You'll need to set up authentication, create a service account key as a .json then have Google Cloud SDK handle it.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

You can also try passing in the service account like this

```
  // Create a new session
  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({keyFilename: "./service_account.json"});
```

Comment: `You'll need to set up authentication, create a service account key as a .json then have Google Cloud SDK handle it` can you please explain how to code this while you are running a private cloud or private nodejs server on heroku?

Comment: `const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({keyFilename: "./service_account.json"});` this solution is not working